# ldapsearch UID and GID from list

Tags: ldap

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the syntax correct for the command below:

```
ldapsearch -v -h enterprise.server.com -xLLL -D "validuser@server.com" -W \
-b "OU=Employees,OU=People,DC=server,DC=com" uidNumber gidNumber -f list.txt > list.out.txt
```

the above command works, it prompts me for my password after I hit enter, but it seems to ignore the "list.txt" option I specify at the end and produces a list of "every" user in our AD database. All I want to is for the command to go by the list file. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide example of `list.txt` content in your question.

Answer (score 1):

According [ldapsearch documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch) when use `-f <file>` option you **must** specify search filter in your ldap command with only single occurrence of `%s` whitch is replaced with a line from `<file>`.

As i see you don't specify LDAP search filter in you command.